# Don't insult my intelligence

Tags: support, suggested-edits, review-audits

[image: Audit]

At least the audits could try to be subtle :p

I understand the "making sure you're paying attention", but even if I weren't this audit is just a tad too obvious... Unless that's by design?

Comment: They are designed not to be subtle. If you fail those ... And yes, people do. Well, I say "people" ...

Comment: They're only easy as long as the original post isn't *already* full of meaningless gibberish. ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is by design.

Review audits are like this to catch those "robo-reviewers" who really aren't paying attention, so subtlety doesn't come into it.

You'd be surprised at the number of users that fail.

Comment: All righty then :) And... honestly, I probably wouldn't be surprised, now I think about it.